# JSONArray error while connecting android to mobile db

Tags: java, php, android, sql

I am trying to connect to my online database with android. After following a tutorial I came up with this piece of code:

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.4/~jasptack/Software%20engineering/connector.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
           }

        //convert response to string
        try{
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
               sb = new StringBuilder();
               sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
               String line="0";
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                              sb.append(line + "\n");
               }
               is.close();
               result=sb.toString();
               }catch(Exception e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
               }
      //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","x-co: "+json_data.getInt("x-coordinaat")+
                                ", straat: "+json_data.getString("straat")
                        );
                }
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:
12-04 23:25:07.711: E/log_tag(353): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

Can anybody help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Please post JSON you are getting from  your service.   It could be that your array is wrapped inside object

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the JSON string is malformed. Make sure that the `String` `result` is a valid `JSONArray` (Should start with '['). Also, you can try mapping `result` to a `JSONObject` instead. If these are fine, one of the elements inside the `JSONArray` is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

I once tried parsing a JSON String returned by my web service. Here is what I did:

The response I got from the web service was:

> {"checkrecord":[{"rollno":"abc2","percentage":40,"attended":12,"missed":34}],"Table1":[]}

In order to parse I did the following:

```
      JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
      JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("checkrecord"); 
      int max = array.length();
      for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) 
   {
      JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(j);
      JSONArray names = obj.names();

     for (int k = 0; k < names.length(); k++) 
   {
      String name = names.getString(k);
      String value= obj.getString(name);  

   }
```

My JSONObject looks like this:

> {"Table1":[],"checkrecord":[{"missed":34,"attended":12,"percentage":40,"rollno":"abc2"}]}

This is what the @500865 was trying to suggest. I just gave a code sample to you. Check your result first and determine whether it is valid. Also check JSONArray result.
If possible post it over here.

Hope it helps

Cheers

Comment: there may be a problemen with the connection to the webservice itself, because when I log the result variable(where I wrote the sb.toString() to), I get the phpfile itself:
<?php
    mysql_connect("http://wilma.vub.ac.be/~se3_1112/phpmyadmin","se3_1112","*********");
    mysql_select_db("se3_1112");
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from locatie");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[]=$row;
    print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close();
    ?>

Comment: Yes if that might be the case ,I suggest u solve the issue with the web service first and get the desired result. Once u get that u can proceed the way I have explained in my answer for parsing JSON

Comment: I solved my problem: a faulty php file was causing some problems that were not detected by the debugger
thx for the help anyway:)